# Connect Visual Studio 2010 Professional to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, codeplex

Is it possible to connect Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition to TFS (project hosted on Codeplex)?

This states, it is not included in Professional edition:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products

However, for VS 2008, there was separate download of Team Explorer and it was posible also for Professional version.

Is this changed for VS 2010?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Team Explorer is included in most editions of Visual Studio 2010.  Try going to the View menu and if Team Explorer is listed then you have it installed.

If you do need to download Team Explorer then you can do so from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=fe4f9904-0480-4c9d-a264-02fedd78ab38

Note that TFS is licensed on a per-user basis on people connecting to the server needing to be covered by a Client Access License (CAL).  If you have Visual Studio without an MSDN subscription then you also need to purchase a TFS CAL to be licensed to use TFS.  (A new benefit of MSDN Subscriptions with the Visual Studio 2010 release is that all levels now include a TFS CAL as well as a full TFS license)

M.

Comment: The link within is no longer active - "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Answer (score 4):

The TFS client is included with most editions (Professional & above).  No separate install.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonba/archive/2010/02/11/team-explorer-is-included-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Ultimate Version and I have a Team Tab at the top that has a "Connect to Team Foundation Server" option as well as a Team Explorer Tab.

I just looked through my msdn account and I see a "Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010" as a separate download.