# Visual Studio does not support source control project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

I am trying to open a project in VS 2010, but i am getting an error while opening it. 
Can any one tell what this error means?

> The Project is under Source Control. This Version of Visual studio
>   .net does not support source controled project .Any Changes make to
>   this project will not propagate to source code

Comment: Thanks for all.. Guys here is what i did , I copied Microsoft.Version.Number.Targets file to " C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\AssemblyInfoTask " this folder and it started working. I dont no what happen but it's working.

Comment: What's happening is you are only changinga copy of the code. If you want to push the changes back into whatever source control it's in you have 'erm issues.

Answer (score 7):

C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache\VersionControl.config

was corrupted.  Deleted it all works now.

Comment: Worked for me too. I'd already tried uninstalling / re-installing VS. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This means that:

1. The project is under Source Control
2. If you make any changes, VS will not propogate them to the Source Control
3. If you need to commit changes to the Source Control, you need to do it in your own way.

**But**, if you want just run the project, or just see the code, or jsut do not want to collaborate with it, you should ignore this message.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is to locate your Visual Studio 2008 development environment executable at the Command Prompt (it’s at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe by default) and type:

devenv /resetskippkgs

Possibly, this will help u, check this out...
[["the project type is not supported by this installation" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336235/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336235/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation-error)

[[asp.net mvc 1.0 "project type is not supported" on Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404104/asp-net-mvc-1-0-project-type-is-not-supported-on-visual-studio-2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404104/asp-net-mvc-1-0-project-type-is-not-supported-on-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Visual Studio **Express**, which does not support add-ins, and therefore does not support source control add-ins.

There's a similar question over here:
[Source Versioning for Visual Studio Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835/source-versioning-for-visual-studio-express)

Answer (score 0):

This means that the solution you opened is under version control, like Team Foundation Server (TFS). To work with the versioning features you need a special version of visual studio.

As it seems (assumption based on the error message) you can use the source from the project, you can build and start the programm, but you cannot commit any changes you made to the versioning repository.

The wikipedia page about TFS explains pretty well what TFS is about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server

If you working with the code for yourself, it shouldn't be a problem. If you work on a team project, using TFS as versioning system, you would have to upgrade to another VS version.

Maybe this stack overflow thread can help you a bit: [Connect Visual Studio 2010 Professional to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633262/connect-visual-studio-2010-professional-to-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it means you are using the express version, and in that you don't get integrated source control.

Need more info like confirming the above and knowing what sort of source control the project is in.