# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate source control error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am trying to open a VS 2010 project with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. The project is under source control (TFS) and I want to open it from the local folder. After opening, I get an error:

```
The Project is under Source Control. This Version of Visual studio .net does 
not support source controlled projects. Any changes that you make to this project 
will not be propagated to source code.
```

And then a message

```
Exception details:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed to load.
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

The solution is then showing with an unavailable project. I don´t think it can be a version problem because I use VS Ultimate. There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106041/visual-studio-does-not-support-source-control-project) about this problem, but I could not make very much of the answers

Comment: Had you been working in tfs previously? Did you delete your tfs cache folder?

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you, I did that, but the same error!

Comment: And have you been working in tfs previously? Did you try reseting the visual studio packages? Does this happen on other workstations?

Comment: yes, but not from this local machine. Usually I have no permissions to work there, so I won´t change a lot. I recognized a strange check-in policy error -could not check in either-, can this hang together somehow?

Comment: And you did make sure that 1) you are using the latest sp for tfs on that machine 2) tfs is selected in vs properties as source control? Is it a custom check-in policy?