# Visual Studio 2008 does not support source controlled projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, version-control

I am trying to open source control projects in Visual Studio 2008, but I'm getting an error, but I am able to open the project without source control.

> The project is under source control. This version of Visual Studio .net does not support source controlled projects. Any changes make to this project will not propagate to source code

Comment: First of all it does. I have run it with source control integration for years. What is the source code provider that you need to use?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 should support source control. You can try out the solutions in this thread and see if it solves your problem:
[Visual Studio does not support source control project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106041/visual-studio-does-not-support-source-control-project)